# Adding formatting to single letters of ggplot title without flanking spaces

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, expression

I have a set of figures I'm creating to highlight single base mutations. I want the figures to have titles that highlight just the single base change in the codon of interest, i.e. "Stuff (CC**C** -> CC**G**)". However, I can't seem to figure out how to create an expression that highlights a single character without adding in flanking spaces (using tilde evaluation). I tried using `paste0()` inside `expression` with `bquote` outside but couldn't seem to get anything that was perfectly functional. Any ideas?

Test plot:
*(Slight preference to underlining, which I've used here, but I'd take bold if the promised markdown formatting has been implemented in ggplot, but it looked like it was still in development as of writing.)*

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  ggtitle(expression("Stuff (CC"~underline("C")~" -> CC"~underline("G")~")"))
```

[image: Product of above code, which includes unwanted flanking spaces]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the individual text elements with `paste` within `expression`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Stuff (CC", underline("C"), " -> CC", underline("G"), ")")))
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! I don't know why I didn't think to try with paste itself, but it works perfectly. Thanks!